# error ~node_modules/node-sass: Command failed Exit code: 1 Command: node scripts/build.js when running rails new application

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm

```
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: ~/workspace/testest/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.4.0/bin/node ~/workspace/testest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (~workspace/testest/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (~workspace/testest/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! command "~.nvm/versions/node/v15.4.0/bin/node" "~workspace/testest/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd ~workspace/testest/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v15.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Really have no idea what actually happens. I don't know when this happened (I built a lot of rails apps for my study but had no problem before) but just recently noticed.

Comment: Are you running the project on a windows machine?

Comment: Thank you sir, I am running it on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Can you verify that you have python installed

Comment: After typing python3 -V, 3.8.5 appears

Comment: Ok since you're using `python3` change `which python` to `which python3` in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have python installed on your machine.

On your terminal RUN `which python`

It should return your python location path that looks something like

`/usr/local/bin/python`

Then run

`npm config set python </usr/local/bin/python>`

OR

just RUN `export PYTHON="$(which python3)"`

Comment: As mentioned above, I already installed python3 with the version of 3.8.5 on my ubuntu

Comment: Just change `which python` to `which python3`